# Can a women work without her husband's permission?

Tags: women, work, wife

Nowadays, women are attracted to working outside the home. As they are being educated, they don't want to live as a housewife. It is true that some of the women are in need of job, but most of them want to be self-dependent. Sometimes, they even don't care about their husband. So, I want to know what is the husband's role in this case? What is his right? What can women do with and without the permission of her husband?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to all Religion, Wife must obey her husband and do accordingly. Allah said that, "If I allowed you(women) to bow down in front of anyone, it would be you husband.". From this, the significance of husband is clear.

Comment: ugh the quote "If I allowed you(women) to bow down in front of anyone, it would be you husband..." is not from the Quran but something  The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said.

Comment: @Damion still the wife isnt obligated to serve him, obey every halal commands, but he is obligated to make a loving bond with her, accommodate her, protect her. morever, the hadith you provided is hassan not sahih

Answer (score 0):

A woman can work from home, and interact with the outside world by means such as by using an agent to act on her behalf, or by sending a letter, or by email, or by a voice call, or by using a remote freelancing website, or by using using any other collaboration tools etc. This is permissible.

As for going out of the house to work, then in principle it is not permitted, because Islam teaches women to observe hijab and to remain at their homes.

> وقرن في بيوتكن ولا تبرجن تبرج الجاهلية الأولى
>
> And abide in your houses and do not display yourselves as [was] the display of the former times of ignorance.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:33](https://quran.com/33/33?translations=20)</sup>

> المرأة عورة، وإنها إذا خرجت استشرفها الشيطان، وإنها لا تكون إلى وجه الله أقرب منها في قعر بيتها
>
> Woman is ‘awrah (that which must be concealed), and when she goes out the Shaytaan’s hopes are raised. She is never closer to Allaah than in the inner part of her house.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Ibn Khuzaimah](https://shamela.ws/index.php/book/1446/2756) and [Saheeh Ibn Hibban](https://shamela.ws/book/1729/8255)</sup>

Especially, a woman is not permitted to leave her house without the permission of her husband, there is Ijma' on this:

> مسائل الإجماع والاتفاق في باب ... وعلى أنه يجب على الزوجة طاعة زوجها وملازمة المسكن، وعلى أن له منعها من الخروج
>
> The matters of consensus and agreement in this topic are ...
>
> It is obligatory on the wife to obey her husband and to remain in her house, and it is the right of the husband to forbid her from going out
>
> <sup>— [Mizan al-Kubra](https://archive.org/details/msha3ranya/mshrn3/page/n195/mode/2up)</sup>

Some of the jurists have explicitly specified the husband's right to forbid his wife from employment (ijarah):

> وله منعها من إجارة نفسها
>
> The husband has the right to forbid her from giving herself for hire
>
> <sup>— [Zaad al-Mustaqni‘](https://shamela.ws/book/11230/224)</sup>

There are exceptions to this when there is a necessity. For example the exceptions relevant to earning are where the husband or family can not provide enough sustenance. Or when the woman needs to go out to fulfill a personal obligation or a communal obligation such as being a midwife.

Further there are conditions for a woman working such as permission of her husband, observance of hijab and abstinence from adornments, segregation from men, traveling with a mahram when required etc. You can see e.g. https://islamqa.info/en/answers/106815/

Comment: cant she work when her husband earns enough with proper hijab?
 can u read please [bin baz](https://ketabonline.com/ar/books/5992/read?part=19&page=8307&index=2236731/2236768/2236769/2236796) and [Al Mausuatul Fiqhiyah Al Quwaitiyyah 7/83](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/4100#p1) ?

Comment: can you examine them?